# Is there anything like Stack Overflow for discussions?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I'm going to write an article why I think a new GUI Library needs to be developed. Is there any place to do this? It would be a longer blog style article, so not something what IMHO belongs on Stack Overflow. But for obvious reasons I don't want to start just another blog.

So do I have to wait for a DiscussionOverflow.com or is there already something like it?

Comment: Why not start "just another blog"? SO is designed as a Q&A site, not one for discussions.

Comment: Go start a blog and leave SO alone.

Comment: @Neil: Yes i know this. But it is a weakness and SO should evolve away from a pure Q&A site.

Comment: It's not a weakness, it's their target. You don't see starbucks selling hamburgers do you?

Comment: @Lothar That's your opinion. Most of us see it as a great strength.  I think you may be in a very small minority on this.

Comment: Stackoverflow is almost dead now, thanks to the strict Q&A style. The only articles still worth reading and popping up in my searches are from the first years (for me this 2012).

Comment: It's somehow available now: https://stackoverflow.co/labs/discussions/

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow - the technology, not just the site - does not handle discussions well. The voting and answer acceptance mechanism are built to find the best (and most likely to be correct) answer to a question.

A forum or blog might be better for what you're trying to do, although I can see how neither is perfect.

Comment: I disagree about the voting. The voting system finds the most popular post, that's it. It happens to usually be the correct answer in the context of Q&A, but the subjective questions on SO show that it can handle popularity contests

Comment: @Bob or on Meta, the amount of memes in your post

Answer (score 2):

http://www.notconstructive.com/ "A place for the discussions not allowed on Stack Overflow"

Tangentially relevant:

http://www.discourse.org/

Jeff Atwood, StackOverflow founder, frames Discourse as a complement to StackOverflow that focuses on discussion:

"At Stack Exchange, one of the tricky things we learned about Q&A is that if your goal is to have an excellent signal to noise ratio, you must suppress discussion.
...
After spending four solid years thinking of discussion as the established corrupt empire, and Stack Exchange as the scrappy rebel alliance, I began to wonder – what would it feel like to change sides? What if I became a champion of random, arbitrary discussion, of the very kind that I'd spent four years designing against and constantly lecturing users on the evil of?
"

http://blog.codinghorror.com/civilized-discourse-construction-kit/

But Discourse is just software for a forum, not itself a forum focused on programming.

Comment: Poking at the not constructive site, there seems to be *very* little activity.  Post categories such as "Java discussions" are closed ([link](http://www.notconstructive.com/t/java-discussions/14)).  Is this an active community? or is this post an advertisement for it?

Comment: I'm unbelievably sad that notconstructive.com is no longer alive.

Answer (score 0):

That type of post would only belong on SO as an answer to a question. But let's be serious -- it looks pretty strange asking a "fake" question, then immediately providing a 6000 word perfectly-proofread answer. (Note: all posts are constrained to a certain number of characters, short enough that it's not suitable for this type of post -- that is by design.)

I think what you're really looking for is to (a) post what you think about a topic, and then (b) get feedback on it. This is precisely how a blog works -- it may be cliché to start a blog these days, but that's the best medium for this type of content, IMO.

Comment: I know a blog it is the best medium. But it definitely isn't if you have a low volumne or even worse a single article blog.

So i tried to ask if there is something i would call an open blog aggregator. Where many people can talk about it something like SlashDot but not for news but for technical articles.

Comment: @Lothar: If you're considering writing more in the future, then you could still post on a new blog, but ask for feedback from a programming forum where you link to the article.

Answer (score -1):

Make a google search for "programming forums"

Answer (score -2):

Use [Quora](http://www.quora.com). and [Disqus](https://disqus.com/). There are lots of topics in there, so you may find where to fit.